# Does the new "enter password to do backup" fix a security hole?

Tags: ipad, backup, security, ventura

I don't have a device to test on, but I'm half-remembering from long ago that I can hook up a new (or found/stolen?) iPad and be offered the opportunity to do a backup on it.

If that is not the case, then the new Ventura feature that demands a passcode on the iPad is a useless inconvenience.  But if it is the case, it fixes a serious security flaw.

Before, if the backup is not encrypted, then I could (and did) access any file on the iPad by [getting into the backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429312/getting-files-from-ipad-that-cant-be-seen-in-finder/429490#429490).

**Is my memory wrong?  Or if the iPad never had a lock code set, is there still a risk?**

There are suggestions of another question that **does** partially answer that it is/was a security problem.  But "is X a security hole?" is **not** a duplicate of "How do I turn X off?"  Also the other doesn't answer whether the vulnerability still exists when the iPad never had a security code set.  Also, the CVE cited says that *applications* can get into the backup while I noted over a year ago that a human (me) can get into it.  But I guess Finder, Terminal, and SQLite are all applications.  (I used SQLite, but I could have used Finder or command line.)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, but the answer does (partially) answer my question by linking to the description of the security issue.  Surprising that it took them this long to find it.

Comment: It is an iOS change, not Ventura. And it is a duplicate.

Comment: "is X a security hole?" is _not_ a duplicate of "How do I turn X off?"  And it started happening when I updated MacOS, NOT when I updated the other devices.

Comment: To offer any kind of protection, it must be an iOS feature. And AFAIR it‘s older than „this year“, maybe the Ventura upgrade triggered a re-authentication.

Comment: According to the CVE, the change was in IOS 15.7.1, which was 27 October.  Ventura was released 25 October—it's quite possible that I just did not do any backup for those roughly 48 hours.

Comment: This question is closed, but I'll try to answer anyways: No, the new "enter pass code to do a backup" does not close a security hole. The CVE that is mentioned here is (confusingly) not about requiring pass codes for backups. This is a case where it is not clear what the desirable behavior is exactly - it varies from person to person. Apple has chosen option A in the past, and now they decided for option B. Both are valid options - neither is a security hole as such. It depends on your individual circumstances. Apple must have decided that now more people expect case B than A, so it's changed.

Comment: Basically it boils down to what you would expect when connecting an unencrypted device to your computer. If you think of the iPad as just another type of USB storage, then you would expect the data on the iPad to be available for the computer when connected - unless it is encrypted ofcourse. This is how USB hard drives, SSD and pen drives work. However, if you instead expect the iPad to work more like a computer, you might expect there to be some kind of authentication before data can be transferred - even though the data is there in clear text. I.e. with a standard PC, the user could [...]

Comment: [...] just remove the hard drive or SSD from the PC and read out the data manually (as it is not encrypted).

Comment: Note that these backups can be taken only by a computer that has previously been trusted by the iPad (which would require entering the pass code, if one were set). I.e. if you have never connected this iPad to that particular computer before - it wouldn't be possible to transfer data without entering a pass code. Also note that an unencrypted backup only contains parts of the data stored on the iPhone - an encrypted backup is required to copy more sensitive data.

Comment: What the CVE is about is what happens with the backup when it is stored on your Mac. Remember that trusted Macs have this particular ability to create backups. In "the olden days" (i.e. before approx. 2018) - any file stored on your Mac is basically "free game" as long as you have got file system permissions to read it. That includes an unencrypted backup of an iOS devices. On newer systems, an extra layer of protection known as TCC is set in place. More specifically on recent systems, you wouldn't actually be able to just access the unencrypted backup without being able to authenticate [...]

Comment: [...] via a particular application for TCC. I.e. if you wanted to open the uencrypted backup with application X, you would need to enter your password in order to give X the permission to read the backup. Even though the file system permissions indicate that it could read the backup. And now we get to what the CVE is about - it is merely about the fact that if you actively choose to store your backup in a different file system location on your Mac than the default - then it would no longer be protected by TCC. [...]

Comment: [...] This could be a problem for some people that had been content with the relatively low security of unencrypted backups as long as not any application could read their contents due to TCC. If they choose to store the backup in a different folder, that protection would (confusingly) be gone.

Comment: All in one this change is an annoyance to those who had an automated backup system set in place, where the iPad could be connected to the trusted computer that would transfer an unencrypted backup without requiring manual user interaction - but would require entering a password when _reading_ data from the backup. On the other hand, it is a positive change for those that do not want to rely on TCC for protecting the backup, and instead wanted it to be harder to get the unencrypted data out of the iPad in the first place.